# C++ Visual Studio how to know which dependencies are needed

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm working on a project for a client and with the MDd code generation option (Dynamically linking visual studio DLL's) the file size is about 25kb.

When I do MTd code generation (statically linking visual studio DLL's) the file size is way larger about 725kb.

How can I find out exactly which DLL's are needed and manually statically link them so taht my file size is not as large as the 725kb but still able to run without needing visual studio runtime DLL's?

Comment: its not necessary you would have ability to statically link at all, it depends if your artifacts have static versions

Comment: Visual Studio would do it more correctly than a manual attempt to do that kind of linking. Anyway you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to identify the dependencies.

Comment: So running the statically linked version via dependency walker and then manually adding in those libs/dll's would be the solution?

Comment: What makes yoou think that 725 isn't already the minimum? Have you turned on link time optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The people who wrote the linker aren't complete idiots. If it's including 725K in your executable, it's because you (directly or indirectly) used 725K of code in your executable.

There is one minor detail to consider though. "MDd" and "MTd" sound a lot like you're including debug information in your executable. If that's the case, consider the possibility of removing the debug information. That can (typically will) reduce the executable size substantially.

If you want to work at it, there's a pretty fair chance you can reduce the size even more, but it won't be by trying to do the linker's job better than it does. It'll be by rewriting your code so it doesn't depend on as much external code. It probably won't be an entirely trivial task. You have to ask yourself whether it's worthwhile to save 500Kb. At one time (30 years ago) there probably wouldn't have been much question about that. Nowadays, putting even an hour or two into saving ~500K sounds questionable at best (at least under most circumstances).

Why is 725K an issue? Do you need to fit your executable on a single 360K floppy?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. Closed captioning for the humor impaired: yes, I realize 360K floppies are thoroughly obsolete.</sup>

Comment: I'll switch to release mode. But I still can't see that shaving off more than 50% at best no?  My thing is I had it down to 25kb when using DLL's but when using it statically linked the size is 25x the original.  I was just curious if it was possible to reduce that drastic increase by half or more.  Hopefully a release build will do that.  In my opinion I can care less about the file size but it's the client request to keep it at minimum.

Comment: Switching to release mode got it from 725 to 75kb Nice suggestion :)